# CCTV Automatic number plate recognition and integration of data,software?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, computer-vision, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I have a client who is looking for a solution to integrate cctv with a (any) ANPR solution that can,I assume recognize the number plate of cars and store in a database and has the ability to post this data to other backoffice applications, crm, marketing app. etc.

Is there any ready software to do this ? Or your recommendations ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recognize vehicle license / number plate (ANPR) from an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981378/how-to-recognize-vehicle-license-number-plate-anpr-from-an-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at:
[How to recognize vehicle license / number plate (ANPR) from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981378/how-to-recognise-vehicle-licence-number-plate-anpr-from-an-image)

There seems to be at least a few ANPR solutions. My advice is to be prepared to buy something if you want a reliable and fully integrated solution.

Comment: do you have anything I could buy

Answer (score 1):

Avigilon currently has a License Plate Recognition Kit. It comes with either one or two lanes. The kit is the camera in a special housing along with a software package that captures the license plates and stores them in a database. You could then search for license plates or create a watch list for specific license plates. You can read more at www.Avigilon.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It is free and open source and is very fast and accurate.  Given an image it will recognize all the license plates and give you the text of the characters.

Since it's open source and written in C++, you should be able to integrate this with your application fairly easily.

Comment: ...if you're American or European.

Comment: It's trainable for other countries...