# OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection

Tags: c++, objective-c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I successfully implemented the OpenCV square-detection example in my test application, but now need to filter the output, because it's quite messy - or is my code wrong?

I'm interested in the four corner points of the paper for skew reduction (like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint)) and further processing …

**Input & Output:**
[image: Input & Output]

**Original image:**

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIm24.jpg)

**Code:**

```
double angle( cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2, cv::Point pt0 ) {
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

- (std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >)findSquaresInImage:(cv::Mat)_image
{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > squares;
    cv::Mat pyr, timg, gray0(_image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    int thresh = 50, N = 11;
    cv::pyrDown(_image, pyr, cv::Size(_image.cols/2, _image.rows/2));
    cv::pyrUp(pyr, timg, _image.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ ) {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ ) {
            if( l == 0 ) {
                cv::Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                cv::dilate(gray, gray, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
            }
            cv::findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
                if( approx.size() == 4 && fabs(contourArea(cv::Mat(approx))) > 1000 && cv::isContourConvex(cv::Mat(approx))) {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    if( maxCosine < 0.3 ) {
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return squares;
}
```

***EDIT 17/08/2012:***

To draw the detected squares on the image use this code:

```
cv::Mat debugSquares( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > squares, cv::Mat image )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i< squares.size(); i++ ) {
        // draw contour
        cv::drawContours(image, squares, i, cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());

        // draw bounding rect
        cv::Rect rect = boundingRect(cv::Mat(squares[i]));
        cv::rectangle(image, rect.tl(), rect.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0);

        // draw rotated rect
        cv::RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(cv::Mat(squares[i]));
        cv::Point2f rect_points[4];
        minRect.points( rect_points );
        for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            cv::line( image, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8 ); // blue
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: [Original image can be found here.](http://cl.ly/1e363U230V342g0l123t)

Comment: I think you can adjust the title of the question for something like *Detecting a sheet of paper* , if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: @moosgummi I am looking to have same functionality which you have implemented i.e "Detect the Corners of the captured image/document".How you achieved this ? Would I be able to use OpenCV within my iPhone application ? Please suggest me some better way to have this ..

Comment: @Ajay Download OpenCV sources and take a look at the **squares.cpp** sample. The function I posted in my answer is an improvement of one of the functions available in that source code. :) Yes, you can use OpenCV to take a picture on the iPhone, process it and then display it back on the screen or whatver you want to do.

Comment: @karlphillip I have download the static library rather than copying & creating the clone on that mac, not uses any commands to create the library for iPhone. Just using within the application now would be able to edit the library in the Face Recognition Program ? I am not able to get any start point to work on the same, just getting confused, Can you help me with some code ?

Comment: Have you ever done something with OpenCV? Any application at all?

Comment: thanks so much for this. I've been trying for the longest time to do this (HoughLines, Harris corners, Eigen values). Just about lost my mind until I saw this. Thanks!

Comment: @Ajay Sharma have you implemented the problem you mentioned in the comment.I also need to implement the same problem.Please help me.

Comment: @Gypsa Any how client dropped the idea about the application, so didn't work furthermore in it.

Comment: @moosgummi after you got the squares how have you drawn the suares in the image.Please post the code that need to be added after detecting squares to show the detected squares in the image.

Comment: @Gypsa take a look at my edit …

Comment: @moosgummi I have same error Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() , how i get rid of this problem?

Comment: @Gryphon Please open a new question for this

Comment: @moosgummi +1 for you, Thanks for your code. I implement your code this working fine for me. I am new in openCV so little issue, I wants draw only one rectangle on paper sheet corner, At present it shows many rectangle (green). how can i detect only paper sheet edge rectangle. thanks

Comment: @Gryphon: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495207/opencv-c-sorting-contours-by-their-contourarea/13495209#13495209 The biggest contour should always be the paper

Comment: It's worth noting that the flag CV_RETR_EXTERNAL can be used when finding the countours to reject all contours inside a closed shape.

Comment: are you able to find white paper if the background of tht is white(i mean white paper on white desk not brown or sme other contrast color )... if anyone idea ... plz help  me...

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This is a recurring subject in Stackoverflow and since I was unable to find a relevant implementation I decided to accept the challenge.

I made some modifications to the squares demo present in OpenCV and the resulting C++ code below is able to detect a sheet of paper in the image:

```
void find_squares(Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares)
{
    // blur will enhance edge detection
    Mat blurred(image);
    medianBlur(image, blurred, 9);

    Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        const int threshold_level = 2;
        for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
        {
            // Use Canny instead of zero threshold level!
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if (l == 0)
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); // 

                // Dilate helps to remove potential holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                    gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
            }

            // Find contours and store them in a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            // Test contours
            vector<Point> approx;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                    // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                    // to the contour perimeter
                    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                    // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                    // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                    // contour orientation
                    if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                            fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                            isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                    {
                            double maxCosine = 0;

                            for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                            {
                                    double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                                    maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                            }

                            if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                                    squares.push_back(approx);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this procedure is executed, the sheet of paper will be the largest square in `vector<vector<Point> >`:

[image: opencv paper sheet detection]

I'm letting you write the function to find the largest square. ;)

Comment: For some unknown reason I'm not abled to get it working anymore. It always throws an exception when mixChannels is called, which is strange because it worked a few days ago. `Some OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() == depth) in mixChannels` Do you know this kind of error? The depth of the channels is matching so it's not making sense. I'm working with OSX 10.7.2 and OpenCV 2.3.1

Comment: That's why I use source control. The smallest accidental modification to the code can be easily discovered. If you didnt change anything, try testing with other images and finally recompile/reinstall opencv.

Comment: Ah, got it working – seems like some times photoshop messes the image up … And I'm now using SVN to manage versions. Thanks!

Comment: In some cases the biggest square is not only containing the paper, but other stuff and the smaller squares are more accurate. Do you have any ideas how to prevent that? Input: http://cl.ly/2o3V2g3l3f0e3m0s1p1K Output: http://cl.ly/0L1n1c1P0X172F0E2h0Z

Comment: Are you always working with the same paper size? What you can do is discover the size of the paper's rectangle in a successful detection, then on the other tests, try to find the square that has the closest width/height to that size: this should be an indicator of the paper's rectangle. Or, play along with the parameters of `cvCanny`, `medianBlur` until you find a more generic solution to your problem. For instance, try the value 7 when calling `medianBlur`.

Comment: The fact is that there is no universal way to detect the paper. What you can do is stablish rules for taking the picture, so it favours the algorithm detection.

Comment: I also noticed that the picture in your question has the paper horizontally, while these links you just shared show the paper in a vertical position. I suggest you rotate the image and try again to see if this influences the detection.

Comment: Rotation the image helps in some cases. I also figured out that down- and upscaling to eliminate details in the picutes helps a lot. Now my result looks like this: http://cl.ly/3A04180u0i0N070N1B2r

Comment: Awesome. We shall close this thread and not talk about it anymore! =D But seriously, this is becoming more like a chat (and we shouldn't). We are also using the comments to discuss the problems you are facing beyond what was stated in the original question. I suggest you consider asking new questions in stackoverflow if you have them. You'll also get way more attention that way. Good luck.

Comment: @moosgummi How can I use this code snippet in my iPhone application looking for Square/Rectangle in an image.I didn;t find any help for implementing the code with OpenCV & iPhoneSDK.Is this the code worked for iPhone ?

Comment: OpenCV is pretty much the same for all platforms (Win/Linux/Mac/iPhone/...). The difference is that some don't supported the GPU module of OpenCV. [Have you built OpenCV for iOS already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)? Were you able to test it? I think these are the questions you need to answer before trying anything more advanced. Baby steps!

Comment: @karlphillip I have error Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() , how to remove it?

Comment: @karlphillip I follow your code and draw red rectangle, now how to crop the area inside the rectangle ?

Comment: @karlphillip please look on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493035/boundry-detect-paper-sheet-opencv

Comment: @moosgummi I faced a similar error "Some OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() == depth) in mixChannels". How did you solve it?

Comment: @karlphillip I tested this code and i was able to detect the paper clearly, but it takes so much time. Is the code really heavy? there is an app called SayText where this detection happens in real-time from a video stream. This code would be impractical for real-time, am I right?

Comment: Probably. This is an academic answer, not very practical for the industry. There are all sorts of optimizations you can try, beginning with the definition of the counter located at `for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)`, which is responsible to iterate on every channel of the image. For instance, you can set it to iterate on only one channel :) Don't forget to up vote.

Comment: hey @karlphillip I'm trying to detect square using opencv and used squares.cpp sample,but it is always throws an exception when mixChannels is called.
Some OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() == depth) in mixChannels.
Could you please help me how did you resolved this error.

Comment: A working Java implementation of this code snippet can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18042054/1717562
It also contains some critical and more efficient changes.

Comment: @karlphillip +1 ,I tried the same code , but its give me the answer with 0 squares , same code , same images , i use the function of `angel` and `debug squares` from user and `find squares` from your answer and main from this answer of you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581451/detection-of-rectangular-bright-area-in-a-image-using-opencv`, but it give me the answer as 0

Comment: Thanks @karlphillip i find the error but it drawing so much reactangle's like 33 , should i go for new thread ?

Comment: @Ahmad That's it, it's working. That's the number of rectangles found in your image and **that's exactly what this code is supposed to do**. In the samples image used here, the paper in the image is the LARGEST rectangle, so all I needed to do is write the code to [figure out the largest rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13532779/176769) in the image.

Comment: @karlphillip thnks 4 the help tht i'll solve :) can u plz help me out for my one doubt  ....to find white paper if the background of tht is white(i mean white paper on white desk not brown or sme other contrast color )...

Comment: What exactly is angle?
I understand the part up until you use approxPolyDP after that I dont understand what are you doing.
Please have a look at this question. Is it the same problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137810/find-roi-in-a-webcam-image/19140296?noredirect=1#19140296

Comment: @SilentPro `angle()` is a [helper function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732392/176769). As stated in the answer, this code is based on **samples/cpp/squares.cpp** present in OpenCV.

Comment: im having trouble implementing the code... what i do is in iOS I have this switch and if turned ON it will trigger this block of code. It will then detect the square on the image in UIimageview... im using objective c.. how do i implement this

Answer (score 42):

Unless there is some other requirement not specified, I would simply convert your color image to grayscale and work with that only (no need to work on the 3 channels, the contrast present is too high already). Also, unless there is some specific problem regarding resizing, I would work with a downscaled version of your images, since they are relatively large and the size adds nothing to the problem being solved. Then, finally, your problem is solved with a median filter, some basic morphological tools, and statistics (mostly for the Otsu thresholding, which is already done for you).

Here is what I obtain with your sample image and some other image with a sheet of paper I found around:

[image] [image]

The median filter is used to remove minor details from the, now grayscale, image. It will possibly remove thin lines inside the whitish paper, which is good because then you will end with tiny connected components which are easy to discard. After the median, apply a morphological gradient (simply `dilation` - `erosion`) and binarize the result by Otsu. The morphological gradient is a good method to keep strong edges, it should be used more. Then, since this gradient will increase the contour width, apply a morphological thinning. Now you can discard small components.

At this point, here is what we have with the right image above (before drawing the blue polygon), the left one is not shown because the only remaining component is the one describing the paper:

[image]

Given the examples, now the only issue left is distinguishing between components that look like rectangles and others that do not. This is a matter of determining a ratio between the area of the convex hull containing the shape and the area of its bounding box; the ratio 0.7 works fine for these examples. It might be the case that you also need to discard components that are inside the paper, but not in these examples by using this method (nevertheless, doing this step should be very easy especially because it can be done through OpenCV directly).

For reference, here is a sample code in Mathematica:

```
f = Import["http://thwartedglamour.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/my-coffee-table-1-sa.jpg"]
f = ImageResize[f, ImageDimensions[f][[1]]/4]
g = MedianFilter[ColorConvert[f, "Grayscale"], 2]
h = DeleteSmallComponents[Thinning[
     Binarize[ImageSubtract[Dilation[g, 1], Erosion[g, 1]]]]]
convexvert = ComponentMeasurements[SelectComponents[
     h, {"ConvexArea", "BoundingBoxArea"}, #1 / #2 > 0.7 &], 
     "ConvexVertices"][[All, 2]]
(* To visualize the blue polygons above: *)
Show[f, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.5], 
     Polygon @@ convexvert}]]
```

If there are more varied situations where the paper's rectangle is not so well defined, or the approach confuses it with other shapes -- these situations could happen due to various reasons, but a common cause is bad image acquisition -- then try combining the pre-processing steps with the work described in the paper "Rectangle Detection based on a Windowed Hough Transform".

Comment: is there any major difference in implementation of yours and the one above(ie @karlphilip 's answer) ? I am sorry I couldn't find any in a fast look (except 3 channel-1 channel and Mathematica-OpenCV).

Comment: @AbidRahmanK yes, there are.. I don't use canny neither "several thresholds" to start with. There are other differences, but by the tone of your comment it seems pointless to put any effort on my own comment.

Comment: I see both of you first find the edges, and determine which edge is square. For finding edges, you people use different methods. He uses canny, you use some dilation-erosion. And "several thresholds", may be he got from OpenCV samples, used to find squares. Main thing is, I felt overall concept is same. "Find edges and detect square". And I asked it sincerely, I don't know what "tone" you got from my comment, or what you (understood/misunderstood). So if you feel this question is sincere, I would like to know other differences. Otherwise discard my comments.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK of course the concept is the same, the task is the same. Median filtering is being used, thinning is being used, I don't care from where he took several thresholds idea -- it is just not used here (thus how can it not be a difference ?), the image is resized here, the component measurements are different. "Some dilation-erosion" doesn't give binary edges, otsu is used for that. It is pointless to mention this, the code is there.

Comment: K. Thank you. Got the answer. `Concept is the same`. (I never used Mathematica, so I can't understand the code.)And the differences you mentioned are differences, but not a different approach or major ones. If you still didn For example, check this:

Comment: http://goo.gl/Hv0gV. Its answers have plenty of variety approaches. Not sure how much of them will work. Some of them may be similar, but overall there are a lot of ideas (even my answer also is just a different concept, I didn't ensure it will work, but still another idea). That is actually I was looking. ( Not simply otsu or threshold like that). Anyway, thanks for your answer and +1 for helping out.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I'm not understanding what you are trying to point out. There are differences that I consider "major enough", otherwise I wouldn't have bothered posting an answer. There are other couple of differences that weren't pointed out, but the code is there (again). For more one example, I don't rely on checks like `approx.size() == 4`, which I see as something just waiting to fail for tiny variations in noise or other details during image acquisition. Every step is done in different manners, and I expect this shorter self-contained code shown here to be more robust (but it can fail).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24602/discussion-between-abid-rahman-k-and-mmgp)

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I'm not going to discuss this further in chat, don't have the time. For the other question you linked in, let us start by pointing out that is a completely different matter. One reason there are varied answers there is because people are just guessing on what to do. That task there is one that requires machine learning, with training, testing, and so on. It cannot be properly solved otherwise. It is also a bad question, despite lots of up votes.

Comment: OK brother, then we can stop this discussion here, me too don't have much time(exam season). Differences you mentioned are differences, I agree, but not "major to me", may be for you. So I think it is just matter of difference in perspective. Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain the above code in C++ or Java code for OpenCV? Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Well, I'm late.

---

In your image, the paper is `white`, while the background is `colored`. So, it's better to detect the paper is `Saturation(饱和度)` channel in `HSV color space`. Take refer to wiki [HSL_and_HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Saturation) first. Then I'll copy most idea from my answer in this [Detect Colored Segment in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342025/detect-colored-segment-in-an-image/47343587#47343587).

---

### Main steps:

1. Read into `BGR`
2. Convert the image from `bgr` to `hsv` space
3. Threshold the S channel
4. Then find the max external contour(or do `Canny`, or `HoughLines` as you like, I choose `findContours`), approx to get the corners.

---

This is my result:

[image]

---

The Python code(Python 3.5 + OpenCV 3.3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.12.20 10:47:28 CST
# 2017.12.20 11:29:30 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np

##(1) read into  bgr-space
img = cv2.imread("test2.jpg")

##(2) convert to hsv-space, then split the channels
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

##(3) threshold the S channel using adaptive method(`THRESH_OTSU`) or fixed thresh
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(s, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

##(4) find all the external contours on the threshed S
#_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

canvas  = img.copy()
#cv2.drawContours(canvas, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

## sort and choose the largest contour
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
cnt = cnts[-1]

## approx the contour, so the get the corner points
arclen = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02* arclen, True)
cv2.drawContours(canvas, [cnt], -1, (255,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.drawContours(canvas, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

## Ok, you can see the result as tag(6)
cv2.imwrite("detected.png", canvas)
```

---

Related answers:

1. [How to detect colored patches in an image using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342025/detect-colored-segment-in-an-image/47343587#47343587)
2. [Edge detection on colored background using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899132/edge-detection-in-opencv-android/47899313#47899313)
3. [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/47898407#47898407)
4. [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions/48292371#48292371)

Comment: I tried using S space but still could not get succeed. See this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699893/scanning-a-document-by-using-opencv

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a **quadrangle** instead of a rotated rectangle.
`RotatedRect` will give you incorrect results. Also you will need a perspective projection.

Basicly what must been done is:

- Loop through all polygon segments and connect those which are almost equel.
- Sort them so you have the 4 most largest line segments.
- Intersect those lines and you have the 4 most likely corner points.
- Transform the matrix over the perspective gathered from the corner points and the aspect ratio of the known object.

I implemented a class `Quadrangle` which takes care of contour to quadrangle conversion and will also transform it over the right perspective.

See a working implementation here:
[Java OpenCV deskewing a contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036920/java-opencv-deskewing-a-contour/18041971#18041971)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have detected the bounding box of the document, you can perform a [four-point perspective transform](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) to obtain a top-down birds eye view of the image. This will fix the skew and isolate only the desired object.

---

Input image:

[image]

Detected text object

[image]

Top-down view of text document

[image]

Code

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
import cv2
import numpy

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and sort for largest contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None

for c in cnts:
    # Perform contour approximation
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        displayCnt = approx
        break

# Obtain birds' eye view of image
warped = four_point_transform(image, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("warped", warped)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Can you please provide c++ implementation of above code?

Comment: This is exactly the one I needed!
but i need it in Objectice-C

Answer (score -1):

Detecting sheet of paper is kinda old school. If you want to tackle skew detection then it is better if you straightaway aim for text line detection. With this you will get the extremas left, right, top and bottom. Discard any graphics in the image if you dont want and then do some statistics on the text line segments to find the most occurring angle range or rather angle. This is how you will narrow down to a good skew angle. Now after this you put these parameters the skew angle and the extremas to deskew and chop the image to what is required.

As for the current image requirement, it is better if you try CV_RETR_EXTERNAL instead of CV_RETR_LIST.

Another method of detecting edges is to train a random forests classifier on the paper edges and then use the classifier to get the edge Map. This is by far a robust method but requires training and time.

Random forests will work with low contrast difference scenarios for example white paper on roughly white background.