# How to generate HarrCascade XML for Object Detection with OpenCV?

Tags: xml, ios4, image-processing, opencv, ios-simulator

I need to create **HarrCascade XML** file to use it with **OpenCV for tracking my Square or Rectangle object**, and I have researched and I fond many way to create HaarCascade but none of this explain with iPhoneSDK.

Sample Link : [Haar Classifiers](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#e134e74e)

Also, I have checked for other XML files which are for eyes, nose & other body parts which works very well.So, I hope just generating a new HarrCascade XML file & training the classfiers will solve ma problem.

So, how to create Haar Cascade (xml) for using with OpenCV for iOS ?

Comment: What about using squares.cpp that come with opencv samples to detect squares?

Comment: I am not sure how to use it within my app ? But I tried to change my XML file & it worked.So, just looking for generating new HarrCascade XML & train ma classifiers of ma own.Alternatively, can you help me with squares.cpp. Thanks

Comment: Well, i am not familier with iphone-sdk. But [squares.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)(Its C implementation [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/squares.c?rev=27)) works fine to detect square. I used to detect it each and every square of sudoku and several other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot if you want to detect squares: [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection)

Works fine for me and if you scale down the input image it's fast enough for iOS-devices

Comment: Did you implemented this code with iOS ? If yes, Can you share the code with some working sample ?

Comment: Yes, I got it working. karlphillips answer is easy to convert to Objective-C code if you want. You can even use just the code he answered. After that you just need to use the biggest square for further processing.

Comment: @AjaySharma Would you may accept may answer, if it was helpfull?

Comment: yes that is.I got the idea.But the thing is still I am not able to make in practice.Can you help me with some demo please.