# Image anlaysis in C/C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, analysis

I'm rather novice in C++ and I must realize this schoolar project :

Assume an image in a document containing both texts and images.

There should be a program written in C++ whose the goal is to load the document and extract separately texts and images in order to output it in
some target destinations like UI or file.

Furthermore, if image contains any texts like legends, program should be able to extract it separately too.

Is there an existing c++ library that respond to those requirements ?

Comment: What kind of document? XML? PNG with XMP? PDF? DOC? ODT?

Comment: If this is for school, I don't think they'd want you to just use a library.

Comment: @Robert Fratto we are supposed to use OPENCV...

Comment: we don't know yet what kind of document

Comment: @RobertFratto that's why i'm looking for a tutorial or something useful

Answer (score 4):

Yes, OpenCV. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

Answer (score 4):

No doubt in that, use **OpenCV**.

But remember, you have a long way to go.

**1. First of all, you should be good in C++ and object oriented programming.**

Well, if you are not good, try to learn it first. Check out following link for some best resources : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909323/what-are-good-online-resources-or-tutorials-to-learn-c

**2. Then get OpenCV and install**

Check out [OpenCV homepage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to get info about downloading and installing OpenCV.

**3. Now get and read some good books on OpenCV**

The best book on OpenCV is "**[Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)**" written by Gary Bradsky, main founder of OpenCV.

Second one is "**[OpenCV cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/book)**".

These books contains lots of examples on OpenCV along with description

**4. Check out [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/)**.

OpenCV documentation contains details of complete functions. It also includes a lot of **[tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)**, which are really good for all.

**5. Also try running OpenCV samples. It contains a lot of good programs**

And always, Google is your best friend. Ask everything there first. Come here only when you are lost in your path.

Acquire all the above things. Then you will be really good in OpenCV and i am sure you will enjoy its power. Once you are done with these, you will get enough idea on realizing your project.( Otherwise, you will post new questions every day asking codes to realize your project, which will be useless for you. )

For your understanding, your project include advanced things like [**Optical Character Recognition.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) It is a big topic. So build yourself from basics. And it will take time.

All the best.

Comment: +1 On top of all that, after he get used to OpenCV I would suggest searching stackoverflow for insteresting works using OpenCV, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8863060/176769), that can be used to detect a paper sheet in a picture.