# Finding multiple objects in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, surf

I am currently trying to detect [P Plates]
[image] in images made from panoramas off the top of a car (so the P plates could be coming from in front or behind me, and may be distorted). There may be more than 2 P plates so I would need the ability to detect more than 1 at a time. I have used OpenCV template matching with mixed success, it doesn't seem to cope with P plates on an angle well and I cannot seem to get it to recognise 2 in an image. I have also tried SURF but with no luck. Does anyone have any recommendations for the kind of algorithm I should use here (preferably one that is integrated into OpenCV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to go with [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) using Rob Hess' [SIFT Library](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/sift/). It's using OpenCV and is pretty fast.

Another way is to [detect squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/8863060#8863060) and than use content of the square for further processing.