# Android OpenCV Edge Detection

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv

I am using OpenCV on Android for doing number plate recognition. As part of the process I am using Canny edge detection to find the edges within the image. The problem I am having is that the horizontal edges within the image are not being detected as solid lines. The problems is that because the lines are not solid I cannot detect it as one contour

This is the image that I am running the edge detection on

[image]

This is the result of the edge detection. As you can see the vertical edges of the number plate have been detected as solid lines but the horizontals are dotted.

[image]

Here is my code

```
        org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny(snapshot.getImage(), dst,
            Configurator.PlateDetectCannyThreshold1,
            Configurator.PlateDetectCannyThreshold2,
            Configurator.PlateDetectCannyApperture);
    List<Mat> contours = new Vector<Mat>();
    org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.findContours(dst, contours, new Mat(),
            org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CV_RETR_LIST,
            org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
            new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: You have bad thresholds in Canny. Lower them a bit.

Comment: I have tried that. I should have mentioned that my upper threshold is at 300 and the lower is at 0 for the image above but I have lowered the upper image incrementally down to 0 and it's made no difference

Comment: The upper threshold should be set somewhere around 40<->120, and the lower threshold as 0.4*upper, or upper/3. I think it's always good to read a bit. `wiki canny` on google, and read how canny works. It's important

Comment: I have tried adjusting the thresholds and I have a good understanding of how the algorithm works, but I'm still seeing the same problem with horizontal lines

Comment: From my understanding of the problem is probably going to be caused because of the angle of the line and it not being completely level. I might be able to fix it using OpenCV erode, does anyone know how to get erode to work in Android as my tests just give me a black image

Comment: Same result can be achieved by this: http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-image-processing-edge-detect.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem when i implement document edge detection and used Morphology to dilate the edge for better detection:

```
 Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, new Size(3,3), new Point(1,1));
 Imgproc.dilate(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, kernel);
```

Comment: can you share steps you performed?

Comment: @RBK please refer to [Square Detetection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection?rq=1)  it describes the steps very well.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be using morphological closing operation as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex#void%20cvMorphologyEx%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20CvArr%2a%20temp,%20IplConvKernel%2a%20element,%20int%20operation,%20int%20iterations%29).

Morphological closing operation helps filling small gaps.