# How to select all out of a contour?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a contours of a binary image, I get the largest object, and I want select all out this object to paint it. I have this code:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours( img.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
vector<Rect> boundSheet( contours.size() );
int largest_area=0;
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
  {
   double a= contourArea( contours[i],false);
   if(a>largest_area){
   largest_area=a; 
   boundSheet[i] = boundingRect(contours[i]); 
   }
  }
```

I want to paint everything outside the boundary with `drawContours`, how can I select all out contour?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176184/with-opencv-try-to-extract-a-region-of-a-picture-described-by-arrayofarrays/10186535#10186535). It shows you how to use drawContours() to draw a given contour onto a mask to mask out the contour. If instead you wish to ignore the contour and keep everything outside it, just set the original value of the mask to a positive value and use drawContours() to fill the region of the contour in the mask with 0. That is, invert the value in the example for given in the link.

Comment: Thanks!!!!, it work me :D, only have a problem with the color, i wanted paint gray, what is would have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    // 'contours' is the vector of contours returned from findContours
    // 'image' is the image you are masking

    // Create mask for region within contour
    Mat maskInsideContour = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC1);
    int idxOfContour = 0;  // Change to the index of the contour you wish to draw
    drawContours(maskInsideContour, contours, idxOfContour,
                 Scalar(255), CV_FILLED); // This is a OpenCV function

    // At this point, maskInsideContour has value of 255 for pixels 
    // within the contour and value of 0 for those not in contour.

    Mat maskedImage = Mat(image.size(), CV_8UC3);  // Assuming you have 3 channel image

    // Do one of the two following lines:
    maskedImage.setTo(Scalar(180, 180, 180));  // Set all pixels to (180, 180, 180)
    image.copyTo(maskedImage, maskInsideContour);  // Copy pixels within contour to maskedImage.

    // Now regions outside the contour in maskedImage is set to (180, 180, 180) and region
    // within it is set to the value of the pixels in the contour.

    return 0;
}
```