# How to convert MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f in opencv java api

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to implement the example code of the following 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/)
by using opencv java api. To implement `findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` in java i used this syntax `Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);`.

So now contours should be `List<MatOfPoint> contours =   new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();` rather than `vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;`.

Then i need implement this `approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);`. In java api, Imgproc.approxPolyDP accept argument as `approxPolyDP(MatOfPoint2f curve, MatOfPoint2f approxCurve, double epsilon, boolean closed)`. How i can i convert MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f?

Or is there a way to use vectors as same as c++ interface to implement this. Any suggestion or sample code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

MatOfPoint2f differs from MatOfPoint only in the type of the elements (32-bit float and 32-bit int respectively). The viable option (though with a performance penalty) is to create MatOfPoint2f instance and set its elements (in a loop) to be equal to the elements of of the source MatOfPoint.

There are

```
 public void fromArray(Point... lp);
 public Point[] toArray();
```

methods in both of the classes.

So you can do just

```
 /// Source variable
 MatOfPoint SrcMtx;

 /// New variable
 MatOfPoint2f  NewMtx = new MatOfPoint2f( SrcMtx.toArray() );
```

Answer (score 35):

I realise this question has already been well answered, but to add an alternative for anyone who finds it in the future -

```
Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){
    //Convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
    contours.get(i).convertTo(mMOP2f1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(mMOP2f1, mMOP2f2, approxDistance, true); 
    //Convert back to MatOfPoint and put the new values back into the contours list
    mMOP2f2.convertTo(contours.get(i), CvType.CV_32S);
}
```

Comment: Where is the mMOP2f2 coming from?

Comment: `mMOP2f1` and `mMOP2f2` are local variables of the loop which are omitted in this example. My edit should clarify this.

Comment: How do you know that @coolersport? They could be global variables too.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to declare them as global but it is a bad practice. Content two objects are corresponding/reset to each contour. And it is proven in my case which shares the same loop.

Comment: Those guys rejected my changes which help clarify this code didn't have a clue. Best of luck guys. Look at the first comment/question with two upvotes.

Comment: Those guys rejected my changes which help clarify this code didn't have a clue. Best of luck guys. Look at the first comment/question with two upvotes.

Answer (score 26):

Although this question has already been answered, I believe that the accepted answer is not the best. Converting a matrix to an array and then back comes with quite the performance penalty, both time-wise and memory-wise.

Instead, OpenCV already has a function that does exactly this: convertTo.

```
MatOfPoint src;
// initialize src
MatOfPoint2f dst = new MatOfPoint2f();
src.convertTo(dst, CvType.CV_32F);
```

I have found this to be significantly faster and more memory-friendly.

To convert a MatOfPoint2f to a MatOfPoint, use CvType.CV_32S instead.

Comment: Not working on open CV anymore. So if ppl can verify I can mark it as the accepted answer.