# How to convert from List<MatOfPoint> to MatOfPoint2f?

Tags: java, opencv

I currently have a line of code

`List<MatOfPoint> contours = new Vector<MatOfPoint>();`

which I'm looking to convert to `MatOfPoint2f` so I can call the following function on it:

`Imgproc.arcLength(contours, true);`

However, I'm really not sure how to convert a `List<MatOfPoint>` to `MatOfPoint2f`, which is what `contours` has to be to work with `arcLength`. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: [Perhaps this answer will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273588/how-to-convert-matofpoint-to-matofpoint2f-in-opencv-java-api)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this thread already but I am wondering how to convert `List<MatOfPoint>` to `MatOfPoint`. Could you give me any advice on this? Will I have to loop through it or something?

Comment: I'm assuming you will have a `List<MatOfPoint2f>` so you will have to loop over each `MatOfPoint` to create your appropriate `MatOfPoint2f` element.

Comment: No, it's `List<MatOfPoint>` - no `2f`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Your original question says `List<MatOfPoint>` to `MatOfPoint2f` now you are saying from a List of `MatOfPoint` to a single `MatOfPoint`?

Comment: So I don't have to convert `List<MatOfPoint>` to 'MatOfPoint` before I convert it to `MatOfPoint2f`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want:

```
 List<MatOfPoint> contours;  //already initialized somewhere in your code
 List<MatOfPoint2f> newContours = new ArrayList<>();
 for(MatOfPoint point : contours) {
     MatOfPoint2f newPoint = new MatOfPoint2f(point.toArray());
     newContours.add(newPoint);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I get the following error message though: "The method arcLength(MatOfPoint2f, boolean) in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments (List<MatOfPoint2f>, boolean)"

Comment: Any way we can get rid of the `List<>` side of things?

Comment: You are confusing a List of `MatOfPoint2f` with a single `MatOfPoint2f`.  Just access each element individually to your `arcLength` operation