# Why is pointPolygonTest() method of OpenCV4Android returning -1 for every pixel?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

In the following code, I have carried out the following steps:

1. Loaded an image from sdcard.

[image]

2. Converted it to HSV format.
3. Used `inRange` function to mask out the red color.

[image]

4. Used `findContours` to find the contours.
5. Find the largest contour from those contours.
6. Created an ROI around the largest contour using `boundingRect` and `submat` functions.

[image]

7. Converted this ROI Mat to HSV format.

[image]

8. Iterated through the ROI Mat, and check for each pixel if it lies within the largest contour. **I used the method `pointPolygonTest` to find this out, but it returns `-1` for every pixel, as can be seen from the `Log.i` output [I have pasted here](http://pastebin.com/w3sCCxa9). The question is why? How can I correct this.**

   ```
   private Scalar detectColoredBlob() {
       rgbaFrame = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/rgbaMat4Mask.bmp");

       Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
       Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaFrame, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
       Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/hsvImage.bmp", hsvImage);// check

       Mat maskedImage = new Mat();
       Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), maskedImage);
       Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/maskedImage.bmp", maskedImage);// check

       List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
       Imgproc.findContours(maskedImage, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

       // \/ We will use only the largest contour. Other contours (any other possible blobs of this color range) will be ignored.
       MatOfPoint largestContour = contours.get(0);
       double largestContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(largestContour);
       for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); ++i) {// NB Notice the prefix increment.
           MatOfPoint currentContour = contours.get(i);
           double currentContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(currentContour);
           if (currentContourArea > largestContourArea) {
               largestContourArea = currentContourArea;
               largestContour = currentContour;
           }
       }
       MatOfPoint2f largestContour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(largestContour.toArray());// Required on Line 289. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273588/how-to-convert-matofpoint-to-matofpoint2f-in-opencv-java-api

       Rect detectedBlobRoi = Imgproc.boundingRect(largestContour);
       Mat detectedBlobRgba = rgbaFrame.submat(detectedBlobRoi);
       Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/detectedBlobRgba.bmp", detectedBlobRgba);// check

       Mat detectedBlobHsv = new Mat();
       Imgproc.cvtColor(detectedBlobRgba, detectedBlobHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
       Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/roiHsv.bmp", detectedBlobHsv);// check

       for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.rows(); firstCoordinate++) {
           for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.cols(); secondCoordinate++) {
               Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY " + Arrays.toString(detectedBlobHsv.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)));
               if (Imgproc.pointPolygonTest(largestContour2f, new Point(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate), false) == -1) {
                   Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY ....................... OUTSIDE");
               }
           }
       }
       Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/processedcontoured.bmp", detectedBlobHsv);// check
   ```

---

***EDIT:***

I am doing this because I need to compute the average HSV color of pixels lying inside the contour (i.e. the average HSV color of the biggest red colored blob). If I computed the average color of the ROI `detectedBlobHsv` by the normal formula, I would do something like

```
Scalar averageHsvColor= new Scalar(256);
Scalar sumHsvOfPixels = new Scalar(256);
sumHsvOfPixels = Core.sumElems(detectedBlobHsv); 
int numOfPixels = detectedBlobHsv.width() * detectedBlobHsv.height(); 
for (int channel=0; channel<sumHsvOfPixels.val.length; channel++) { 
  averageHsvColor = sumHsvOfPixels.val[channel]/numOfPixels; 
}
```

So somebody here on SO (probably you?) had suggested me a way to exclude pixels outside my contour a while back. I'd implement that like:

```
//Giving pixels outside contour of interest an HSV value of `double[]{0,0,0}`, so that they don't affect the computation of `sumHsvOfPixels` while computing average, 
//and while keeping track of the number of pixels removed from computation this way, so we can subtract that number from the `$numOfPixels` during computation of average.
int pixelsRemoved = 0;
for (int row=0; row<detectedBlobHsv.rows(); row++) {
  for (int col=0; col<detectedBlobHsv.cols(); col++) {
    if (Imgproc.pointPolygonTest(largestContour2f, new Point(row, col), false) == -1) {
      detectedBlobHsv.put(row, col, new double[]{0,0,0});
      pixelsRemoved++;
    }
  }
}
```

Then compute the average like

```
Scalar averageHsvColor= new Scalar(256);
Scalar sumHsvOfPixels = new Scalar(256);
sumHsvOfPixels = Core.sumElems(detectedBlobHsv); //This will now exclude pixels outside the contour
int numOfPixels = (  detectedBlobHsv.width()*detectedBlobHsv.height()  )-pixelsRemoved; 
for (int channel=0; channel<sumHsvOfPixels.val.length; channel++) { 
  averageHsvColor = sumHsvOfPixels.val[channel]/numOfPixels; 
}
```

---

***EDIT 1:***

Towards the end of the following method, I have created the mask with a list of `MatOfPoint`s which contains the *largest* contour only. When I wrote it to SDCard, I got

[image]

**I don't know where I messed up!**

```
private Scalar detectColoredBlob() {
        //Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/rgbaFrame.jpg", rgbaFrame);// check
        rgbaFrame = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/rgbaMat4Mask.bmp");


        //GIVING A UNIFORM VALUE OF 255 TO THE V CHANNEL OF EACH PIXEL (255 IS THE MAXIMUM VALUE OF V ALLOWED - Simulating a maximum light condition) 
        for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate < rgbaFrame.rows(); firstCoordinate++) {
            for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate < rgbaFrame.cols(); secondCoordinate++) {
                double[] pixelChannels = rgbaFrame.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate); 
                pixelChannels[2] = 255;
                rgbaFrame.put(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate, pixelChannels);
            }
        }


        Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaFrame, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/hsvImage.bmp", hsvImage);// check


        Mat maskedImage = new Mat();
        Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), maskedImage);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/maskedImage.bmp", maskedImage);// check


        // Mat dilatedMat = new Mat();
        // Imgproc.dilate(maskedImage, dilatedMat, new Mat());
        // Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/dilatedMat.jpg", dilatedMat);// check


        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(maskedImage, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        //FINDING THE BIGGEST CONTOUR
        // \/ We will use only the largest contour. Other contours (any other possible blobs of this color range) will be ignored.
        MatOfPoint largestContour = contours.get(0);
        double largestContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(largestContour);
        for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); ++i) {// NB Notice the prefix increment.
            MatOfPoint currentContour = contours.get(i);
            double currentContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(currentContour);
            if (currentContourArea > largestContourArea) {
                largestContourArea = currentContourArea;
                largestContour = currentContour;
            }
        }


        Rect detectedBlobRoi = Imgproc.boundingRect(largestContour);
        Mat detectedBlobRgba = rgbaFrame.submat(detectedBlobRoi);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/detectedBlobRgba.bmp", detectedBlobRgba);// check


        Mat detectedBlobHsv = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(detectedBlobRgba, detectedBlobHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/roiHsv.bmp", detectedBlobHsv);// check

        List<MatOfPoint> largestContourList = new ArrayList<>();
        largestContourList.add(largestContour);

        Mat roiWithMask = new Mat(detectedBlobHsv.rows(), detectedBlobHsv.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        roiWithMask.setTo(new Scalar(0,0,0));
        Imgproc.drawContours(roiWithMask, largestContourList, 0, new Scalar(0, 255, 255), -1);//TODO Using -1 instead of CV_FILLED.
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/roiWithMask.bmp", roiWithMask);// check


        // CALCULATING THE AVERAGE COLOR OF THE DETECTED BLOB
        // STEP 1:
        double [] averageHsvColor = new double[]{0,0,0};
        int numOfPixels = 0;
        for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.rows(); ++firstCoordinate) {
            for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate < detectedBlobHsv.cols(); ++secondCoordinate) {

                double hue = roiWithMask.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[0];
                double saturation = roiWithMask.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[1];
                double value = roiWithMask.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[2];

                averageHsvColor[0] += hue;
                averageHsvColor[1] += saturation;
                averageHsvColor[2] += value;

                numOfPixels++;
            }
        }
        averageHsvColor[0] /= numOfPixels;
        averageHsvColor[1] /= numOfPixels;
        averageHsvColor[1] /= numOfPixels;



        return new Scalar(averageHsvColor);
    }
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I corrected my 3 channel mask and made a single channel mask

```
Mat roiMask = new Mat(rgbaFrame.rows(), rgbaFrame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        roiMask.setTo(new Scalar(0));
        Imgproc.drawContours(roiMask, largestContourList, 0, new Scalar(255), -1);
```

and this resulted in the correct `roiMask`:

[image]

Then, before the comment `// CALCULATING THE AVERAGE COLOR OF THE DETECTED BLOB`, I added:

```
Mat newImageWithRoi = new Mat(rgbaFrame.rows(), rgbaFrame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
newImageWithRoi.setTo(new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
rgbaFrame.copyTo(newImageWithRoi, roiMask);
Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/newImageWithRoi.bmp", newImageWithRoi);//check
```

This resulted in:

[image]

**Now again I don't know how to proceed.** :s

Comment: Why you need to do that? Once you have the contour, or the mask, you already now which points are inside.

Comment: @Miki Please see the edit in the question, I stated it there.

Comment: I _hardly_ reccomended to use `pointPolygonTest` :D. See answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `pointPolygonTest`, because you already have the mask.

You can simply sum up the values that lies on the mask. Something along the lines of (not able to test this):

```
// Initialize at 0!!!
Scalar averageHsvColor= new Scalar(0,0,0);

int numOfPixels = 0;

for(int r=0; r<detectedBlobHsv.height(); ++r)
{
    for(int c=0; c<detectedBlobHsv.width(); ++c)
    {
        if( /* value of mask(r,c) > 0 */) 
        {
            int H = // get H value of pixel at (r, c)
            int S = // get S value of pixel at (r, c)
            int V = // get V value of pixel at (r, c)

            // Sum values
            averageHsvColor[0] += H;
            averageHsvColor[1] += S;
            averageHsvColor[2] += V; 

            // Increment number of pixels inside mask
            numOfPixels ++;
        }
    }
}

// Compute average
averageHsvColor[0] /= numOfPixels ;
averageHsvColor[1] /= numOfPixels ;
averageHsvColor[2] /= numOfPixels ;
```

Comment: _"because you already have the mask"_, and _"`if( /* value of mask(r,c) > 0 */)...`"_ - Which mask are we talking about? Do you mean I should create a mask from `detectedBlobHsv` by doing `Imgproc.drawContours(anEmptyMatForMask, aListHavingLargestContour, 0, new Scalar(255), -1);`?

Comment: In that case, I can't have something like `if (anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c) > 0)` because `anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c) ` would return a double, so it can't be compared with `0` :s

Comment: 1) Yes! 2) Why you can't compare a double with `> 0`?

Comment: Sorry my bad! `anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c)` would return a `double []`, i.e. a double array, whcih can't be compared to int. Anyways I tried it without this `if`, posting the results in an edit int the question.

Comment: `anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c)[0]` should get the correct value

Comment: But that would check only the hue channel, may be I should add this check for saturation and value separately, like `anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c)[1]` and `anEmptyMatForMask.get(r,c)[2]`.

Comment: The mask has a single channel only

Comment: I had it that way in the start: `Mat roiWithMask = new Mat(detectedBlobHsv.rows(), detectedBlobHsv.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        roiWithMask.setTo(new Scalar(0));
        Imgproc.drawContours(roiWithMask, largestContourList, 0, new Scalar(255), -1);` but that gives me ***"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1"*** at `double saturation = roiWithMask.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[1];`, because for single channel Mat, the double[] returned by `roiWithMask.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)` will have only a single element. :s

Comment: I added another edit in the question. The main problem is that masks are single-channel Mats, whereas to compute average, we need all three channels of the original image. I think Masks are not gonna do, I'll have to go with `pointPolygonTest` (though I'd really prefer doing without that - have already wasted more than a day on that), don't you think so?

Comment: With the mask (single channel) you only select if a pixel position `(r,c)` should be used for computing the average or not. Then you compute it on your 3 channel hsv image at position `(r,c)`