# Decompose simple shapes from Binary Images with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

How do I decompose a complex Shape into simple shapes from binary images with OpenCV?  I would post an image...but it is not allowed for new users.  My example is a box overlaid on another box and both boxes are the same exact color(1 color)....I want to break this into two boxes....what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might want to take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/8863060#8863060).

Comment: upload image in imageshack.us and provide link here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Hough transform for your specific concern as it is powerful to detect overlapping parametric forms.

Beware, wikipedia may not be the best source to introduce Hough transform !

Originally Hough transform was used to detect lines inside images but the generalisation of the concept is easy to implement.