# OpenCV for iOS port to Android

Tags: android, ios, opencv

I have already developed an application in iOS which uses [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection) to detect a sheet of paper and I am translating the algorithm to an Android port.

How should I translate this one into Java?

```
mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
```

Where `blurred` and `gray0` are `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [cvMixChannels](http://www.mon-club-elec.fr/mes_docs/my_javacv_javadoc/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.html#cvMixChannels%28com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvArr%5B%5D,%20int,%20com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvArr%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) function. [Here's description](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#mixChannels) of parameters.

Comment: @vasile fernandospr asked to translate one function, not whole code.

Comment: Sorry but if you have the whole code to detect a paper sheet translated that would be great!

Comment: @fernandospr No, I don't have it.

Comment: @astor Using cvMixChannels is not a valid response. It requires to use another wrapper which I would not like to use. Core.mixChannels requires List<Mat> as parameters, instead of just a Mat in the cpp version, please can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
MatOfInt fromto = new MatOfInt(ch);
List<Mat> blurredlist = new ArrayList<Mat>();
List<Mat> graylist = new ArrayList<Mat>();
blurredlist.add(0, blurred);
graylist.add(0, gray0);
Core.mixChannels(blurredlist, graylist, fromto);
```

Look at this implementation for more examples:
https://code.google.com/p/scope-ocr/