# OpenCV contour axis sort

Tags: sorting, opencv

I got this problem. I've found contours in my picture. Approximate them and all that stuff. Now, I want to sort them by Y axis and then by X axis. Is that possible?I'm using std::sort twice for this and I always get sort for one axis only. Please answer ASAP. Thanks

```
bool operator()(vector<Point> c1,vector<Point>c2){
    double a=boundingRect( Mat(c1)).y;
    double b=boundingRect( Mat(c2)).y;
    return a<b;
    }
```

This is an example for Y axis. Using same for X axis (y=>x).

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do (lost by "Approximate them and all that stuff"), but maybe using a custom compare like in this question would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495207/opencv-c-sorting-contours-by-their-contourarea ?

Comment: My teacher said to me to do this - sort contours by Y and then by X axis. I'll try that link you've posted (or I will ask my teacher). Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your teacher wanted you to sort them by Y first, and if the Ys are the same, sort by X. If that's the case, you should write your comparator like

```
bool operator()(const vector<Point>& c1, const vector<Point>& c2) {
  // get bounding boxes for c1 and c2
  cv::Rect bbox1 = boundingRect(cv::Mat(c1));
  cv::Rect bbox2 = boundingRect(cv::Mat(c2));
  // if c1's top is lower than c2's bottom, order should be c2 c1
  if (c1.y > c2.y+c2.height-1) {
    return false;
  }
  // if c2's top is lower than c1's bottom, order should be c1 c2
  if (c2.y > c1.y+c1.height-1) {
    return true; 
  }
  // they have overlap in y direction, just sort them by their x
  return c1.x < c2.x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Maybe i explained my problem wrong. I have this picture: [link](http://chivethebrigade.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/text-end-920-0.jpg?w=920&h=387) and i want to read contours not from top to bottom by cols,but left to right by rows. My teacher told me to sort them by Y and X axis. I greatly appreciate all the advices. Thanks once again.

Comment: Looks like you want to find out all the text in the same text line first, and then sort them by x. For example, you want to get "Thanks everyone for the Patience I'm hoping this is the end of the re-posts" from your sample image. Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: I think this is it. Text in one line and then using Y axis recognize, where one row of text ends and new one begins.

Answer (score 0):

This could be most succinctly accomplished using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), if you have access to C++11 features.

```
bool operator()(vector<Point> c1,vector<Point>c2)
{
    double a=boundingRect( Mat(c1)).y;
    double b=boundingRect( Mat(c2)).y;
    return std::tie(a.y, a.x) < std::tie(b.y, b.x);
}
```

You then only need to call `std::sort` once.