# Java OpenCV deskewing a contour

Tags: java, opencv

I have made some progress detecting a specific kind of object. Actually a card, just like any other in your wallet.

Now I'm stuck with deskewing the photo. See:

[image]

The blue (rounded) rectangle represents the detected contour.
The purple rotate rectangle represents a `RotatedRect` extracted from the detected contour.
The green line is just the bounding box.

Well I need neither of those rectangles. The rectangles both have 90 degree corners. Which won't get me the perspective.

**My question:**

How can I get as accurate as possible all **quadrangle** corners from a contour?

Comment: approximate the corner to a rectangle, get the four corners, find perpective transform, warp the image. Try these links: http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-2.html, http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-3.html

Comment: @AbidRahmanK Thanks for the links. I already got so far. With RotatedRect and affine transformations. What I need, is the corners of the **quadrangle** to do correct transformations.

Comment: try ``approxpoly(contour)``

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I cant use it for the corners because the upper corners are rounded. See the picture.

Comment: any way for perspective transformation, you need four corners. With rounds it is not possible. So approximating contour will convert the rounds to a corner point (of course with some error, but better than rotated rectangle)

Comment: @AbidRahmanK Thanks for your input. I think I will go thinking about a polygon to quadrangle algoritm then.

Comment: OpenCV provides it : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#cv2.approxPolyDP

Comment: @AbidRahmanK Well like you already said, it gave me incorrect results. I'm writing my own now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a class `Quadrangle` which creates the quadrangle of the 4 most largest connected polygon vertices which will intersect each other at some point. This will work in nearly any case.

If you use this code, remember to adjust the width and height in `Quadrangle.warp`. Note that it isn't 100% complete, the first and last polygon vertices won't be connected if they may be connect for example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

class Line {
    public Point offset;
    public double angle;

    public Line(Point offset, double angle) {
        this.offset = offset.clone();
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public Point get(int length) {
        Point result = offset.clone();
        result.x += Math.cos(angle) * length;
        result.y += Math.sin(angle) * length;
        return result;
    }

    public Point getStart() {
        return get(-5000);
    }

    public Point getEnd() {
        return get(5000);
    }

    public void scale(double factor) {
        offset.x *= factor;
        offset.y *= factor;
    }

    public static Point intersect(Line l1, Line l2) {
        return getLineLineIntersection(l1.getStart().x, l1.getStart().y, l1.getEnd().x, l1.getEnd().y,
                l2.getStart().x, l2.getStart().y, l2.getEnd().x, l2.getEnd().y
                );
    }

    public static Point getLineLineIntersection(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
      double det1And2 = det(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      double det3And4 = det(x3, y3, x4, y4);
      double x1LessX2 = x1 - x2;
      double y1LessY2 = y1 - y2;
      double x3LessX4 = x3 - x4;
      double y3LessY4 = y3 - y4;
      double det1Less2And3Less4 = det(x1LessX2, y1LessY2, x3LessX4, y3LessY4);
      if (det1Less2And3Less4 == 0){
         // the denominator is zero so the lines are parallel and there's either no solution (or multiple solutions if the lines overlap) so return null.
         return null;
      }
      double x = (det(det1And2, x1LessX2,
            det3And4, x3LessX4) /
            det1Less2And3Less4);
      double y = (det(det1And2, y1LessY2,
            det3And4, y3LessY4) /
            det1Less2And3Less4);
      return new Point(x, y);
   }
   protected static double det(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
      return a * d - b * c;
   }
}

class LineSegment extends Line implements Comparable {
    public double length;

    public LineSegment(Point offset, double angle, double length) {
        super(offset, angle);
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void melt(LineSegment segment) {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x += Math.cos(angle) * length;
        point.y += Math.sin(angle) * length;
        point.x += Math.cos(segment.angle) * segment.length;
        point.y += Math.sin(segment.angle) * segment.length;

        angle = Math.atan2(point.y, point.x);
        offset.x = (offset.x * length + segment.offset.x * segment.length) / (length + segment.length);
        offset.y = (offset.y * length + segment.offset.y * segment.length) / (length + segment.length);

        length += segment.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object other) throws ClassCastException {
        if (!(other instanceof LineSegment)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("A LineSegment object expected.");
        }
        return (int) (((LineSegment) other).length - this.length);    
    }
}

class Quadrangle {
    static int
        TOP = 0,
        RIGHT = 1,
        BOTTOM = 2,
        LEFT = 3;

    public Line[] lines = new Line[4];

    public Quadrangle() {

    }

    private static double getAngle(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    }

    private static double getLength(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2));
    }

    private static double roundAngle(double angle) {
        return angle - (2*Math.PI) * Math.round(angle / (2 * Math.PI));
    }

    public static Quadrangle fromContour(MatOfPoint contour) {
        List<Point> points = contour.toList();
        List<LineSegment> segments = new ArrayList<>(); 

        // Create line segments
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            double a = getAngle(points.get(i), points.get((i + 1) % points.size())); 
            double l = getLength(points.get(i), points.get((i + 1) % points.size())); 
            segments.add(new LineSegment(points.get(i), a, l));
        }

        // Connect line segments
        double angleDiffMax = 2 * Math.PI / 100;
        List<LineSegment> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (LineSegment segment : segments) {
            if (output.isEmpty()) {
                output.add(segment);
            } else {
                LineSegment top = output.get(output.size() - 1);
                double d = roundAngle(segment.angle - top.angle);
                if (Math.abs(d) < angleDiffMax) {
                    top.melt(segment);
                } else {
                    output.add(segment);
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(output);

        Quadrangle quad = new Quadrangle();

        for (int o = 0; o < 4; o += 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (Math.abs(roundAngle(output.get(i).angle - (2 * Math.PI * o / 4))) < Math.PI / 4) {
                    quad.lines[o] = output.get(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return quad;
    }

    public void scale(double factor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            lines[i].scale(factor);
        }
    }

    public Mat warp(Mat src) {
        Mat result = src.clone();


        Core.line(result, lines[TOP].get(-5000), lines[TOP].get(5000), new Scalar(200, 100, 100), 8);
        Core.line(result, lines[RIGHT].get(-5000), lines[RIGHT].get(5000), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 8);


        Core.line(result, lines[BOTTOM].get(-5000), lines[BOTTOM].get(5000), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 8);
        Core.line(result, lines[LEFT].get(-5000), lines[LEFT].get(5000), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 8);



        Point p = Line.intersect(lines[TOP], lines[LEFT]);
        System.out.println(p);
        if (p != null) {
            Core.circle(result, p, 30, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 8);
        }

        double width = 1400;
        double height = width / 2.15;

        Point[] srcProjection = new Point[4], dstProjection = new Point[4];
        srcProjection[0] = Line.intersect(lines[TOP], lines[LEFT]);
        srcProjection[1] = Line.intersect(lines[TOP], lines[RIGHT]);
        srcProjection[2] = Line.intersect(lines[BOTTOM], lines[LEFT]);
        srcProjection[3] = Line.intersect(lines[BOTTOM], lines[RIGHT]);

        dstProjection[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        dstProjection[1] = new Point(width - 1, 0);
        dstProjection[2] = new Point(0, height - 1);
        dstProjection[3] = new Point(width - 1, height - 1); 


        Mat warp = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(new MatOfPoint2f(srcProjection), new MatOfPoint2f(dstProjection));
        Mat rotated = new Mat();
        Size size = new Size(width, height);
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(src, rotated, warp, size, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
        return rotated;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, it isn't complete, however it works for my specific case for like 90%. You would probably need some tweaking. Second you can use it like: `Quadrangle q = Quadrangle.fromContour(contour);` And then warp it over your src matrix like: `Mat m = q.warp(src);`, then you will have the right perspective of a rotated quadrangle in `m`. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tim , could you please explain more detail in how to use your class above ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Tim I dont know how to use your Quadrangle class . could you guide me pls ?

Comment: Quadrangle q = Quadrangle.fromContour(contour);

Comment: @Tim I Got many contours not a single one. How to use your quadrangle to detect the largest object

Comment: @QadirHussain Just calculate the area of each polygon (contour), see (http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon) then you can pick the largest and construct the quadrangle instance. Or you could ofcourse write the area calculation as method of the Quadrangle class.

Comment: @Tim, I am new in OpenCv, so please can you explain how to use your class to find a rectangular object from an image. I've tried your code  but I'm getting some errors. I think I'm making any mistake. so can u help me to solve these errors

Comment: @VikasKumarTiwari Well this code here is meant to deskew a contour. Not to find one. The code which I used to detect the object can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020455/java-opencv-tesseract-ocr-code-regocnition?noredirect=1&lq=1