# opencv square detection radiant floor prob

Tags: opencv, image-processing, geometry, shapes, edge-detection

working on square detection. the problem is on the radiant floor. as you can see pictures.
any idea for solve this problem ?

thank you.

source image :
[image]

output : 
[image]

source code:

> void EdgeDetection::find_squares(const cv::Mat& image,
>   vector >& squares,cv::Mat& outputFrame) {
>
> ```
> unsigned long imageSize = (long) (image.rows * image.cols) / 1000;
> if  (imageSize > 1200) RESIZE = 9;
> else if  (imageSize > 600) RESIZE = 5;
> else if  (imageSize > 300) RESIZE = 3;
> else RESIZE = 1;
>
>
> Mat src(Size(image.cols / RESIZE, image.rows / RESIZE),CV_YUV420sp2BGR);
> // Resize src to img size
> resize(image, src, src.size() ,0.5, 0.5, INTER_LINEAR);
> ```
>
> Mat imgeorj=image;
>          const int N = 10;//11;
>       Mat pyr, timg, gray0(src.size(), CV_8U), gray;
>
> ```
> // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
> pyrDown(src, pyr, Size(src.cols / 2, src.rows / 2));
> pyrUp(pyr, timg, src.size());
> ```
>
> **#ifdef blured**
>
> ```
> Mat blurred(src);
> medianBlur(src, blurred, 15);
> ```
>
> **#endif**
>
> ```
> vector<vector<Point> > contours;
>
> // find squares in every color plane of the image
> for ( int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
>     int ch[] = {c, 0};
>     mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
>
>     // try several threshold levels
>     for ( int l = 0; l < N; ++l) {
>         // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
>         // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
>         if (l == 0) {
>             // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
>             // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
>             // Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
>             // Canny(gray0, gray, (10+l), (10+l)*3, 3);
>             Canny(gray0, gray,50, 200, 3 );
>             // dilate canny output to remove potential
>             // holes between edge segments
>             dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));
>             //erode(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 1);
>         } else {
>             // apply threshold if l!=0:
>             // tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
>             gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;
>         }
>
>
>         // find contours and store them all as a list
>         findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
>
>         vector<Point> approx;
>
>         // test each contour
>         for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
>             // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
>             // to the contour perimeter
>
>             approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.02, true);
>
>
>             if (approx.size() == 4 &&
>                 fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 5000 &&
>                 isContourConvex(Mat(approx))) {
>                 float maxCosine = 0;
>
>                 for (register int j = 2; j < 5; ++j) {
>                     // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
>                     float cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
>                     maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
>                 }
>
>                 // if cosines of all angles are small
>                 // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
>                 // vertices to resultant sequence
>                 if (maxCosine < 0.3) {
>                     squares.push_back(approx);
>                 }
>
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
> }
>
> debugSquares(squares, imgeorj,outputFrame);
> }
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Hough transform for detecting straight edges and use the those for constructing the square.