# Outline detection in an iOS camera app

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I am working on an app that lets users take photographs of documents. Is it possible to detect the outline of the document and only take photograph of that and ignore the background or other stuff around the document or do I have to rely on the user to take the picture without the background? We can assume the document is white in color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection