# Detect Colored Circles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a bunch of skin images with moles. But unfortunately a large part of the set is containing annoying colored circles which I want to detect & remove. I've tried my best with `cv2.HoughCircles` but the results are completely wrong :(

Does anybody have an idea to detect these more efficiently? I've attached some images and my output.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: My detection]

Comment: What if you did some kind of analysis based on hue (in HSV or similar colour space). Those circles are definitely not skin coloured, so you ought to be able to segment them out reasonably well. | Could you show your current code, please, in some minimal variant -- just so that we can at least see what exactly you did and possibly reproduce it.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to judge whether there exist `colored patches`, you can try use `Saturation` in `HSV` as this: [How to detect colored patches in an image using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342025/how-to-detect-colored-patches-in-an-image-using-opencv/47343587#47343587).

> 1. Convert to HSV from BGR
> 2. Threshold on Saturation channel
> 3. Other steps...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is actually quite good. How would I get the bounding box around the mole?