# Capture area of interest

Tags: python, opencv, roi

Using OpenCV, how can I draw a similar interface and, caputure the ROI inside it ?

How this is called ? It's a opencv mask ? I would like, more than code, know the terms/steps I have to search to achieve this.

[image: aoi]

Comment: try something like: framing, bounding box, contouring

Comment: Try [this](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2015/12/basic-opencv-3-mat-tutorial-part-2-roi.html), it is C++ but you can convert it to python easily.

Comment: @QuangHoang it's not what I am searching for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the image from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342025/how-to-detect-colored-patches-in-an-image-using-opencv/47343587#47343587).

Here is my steps:

> (1) First crop and backup the roi;
>
> (2) Then divide the image by 2;
>
> (3) Then past the roi into the origin image.

---

This is my result:

[image]

---

The code:

```
# 2018/11/29 08:20 (CST)
import cv2

fname = "draw.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(fname)

sx, sy = (70, 120)
rw, rh = (410, 360)

roi = img[sy:sy+rh, sx:sx+rw].copy()
img //= 2
img[sy:sy+rh, sx:sx+rw] = roi

cv2.imwrite("dst.png", img)
```