# OpenCV document detection FIX

Tags: opencv

I need something like here [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/14368605)

My code is working like a charm when my background and foreground is not the same, but if my background is almost the same color as the document it can't work anymore.

Here is the picture with a beige bg + almost beige document what is not working.. Can somebody help in this how can I fix this code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfuXD.jpg

and the code is here:

```
vector<Point> getPoints(Mat image)
{
    int width = image.size().width;
    int height = image.size().height;
    Mat image_proc = image.clone();
    vector<vector<Point> > squares;

    // blur will enhance edge detection
    Mat blurred(image_proc);
    medianBlur(image_proc, blurred, 9);

    Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        const int threshold_level = 2;
        for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
        {
            // Use Canny instead of zero threshold level!
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if (l == 0)
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); //

                // Dilate helps to remove potential holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
            }

            // Find contours and store them in a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            // Test contours
            vector<Point> approx;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }

        double largest_area = -1;
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<squares.size();i++)
        {
            double a =contourArea(squares[i],false);
            if(a>largest_area)
            {
                largest_area = a;
                largest_contour_index = i;
            }
        }

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "Scaning size() %d",squares.size());
        vector<Point> points;
        if(squares.size() > 0)
        {
            points = squares[largest_contour_index];
        }
        else
        {
            points.push_back(Point(0, 0));
            points.push_back(Point(width, 0));
            points.push_back(Point(0, height));
            points.push_back(Point(width, height));
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try to normalize picture?

Comment: I am an android developer so my c++ and opencv skills are very limited. Can you help more?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `threshold` operation in `S` space of `HSV-color-space`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#General_approach

I just split the channels of `BGR` and `HSV` as follow. More operations are needed.

[image]

[image]