# OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Rectangle Detection

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm trying to detect a paper sheet in an image just like [Camscanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner&hl=en).
I've followed the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863060) for this implementation.

This detects the paper sheet on dark backgrounds accurately but not on a light background.

**Sample image:**
[image: Click here]

**Code:**

```
void find_squares(Mat& image, vector<vector<cv::Point> >& squares){
// blur will enhance edge detection
Mat blurred(image);
medianBlur(image, blurred, 9);

Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

// find squares in every color plane of the image
for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
{
    int ch[] = {c, 0};
    mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

    // try several threshold levels
    const int threshold_level = 2;
    for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
    {
        // Use Canny instead of zero threshold level!
        // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
        if (l == 0)
        {
            Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); //

            // Dilate helps to remove potential holes between edge segments
            dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
        }
        else
        {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
        }

        // Find contours and store them in a list
        findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // Test contours
        vector<cv::Point> approx;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                        fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                        isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                {
                        double maxCosine = 0;

                        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                        {
                                double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                                maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                        }

                        if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                                squares.push_back(approx);
                }
        }
    }
}}
double angle( cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2, cv::Point pt0 ) {
double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);}
```

Comment: Paper color and the bacground color is very similar to each other so it ll be very difficult to get a good result. Did you try that example with CamScanner? Does it give good results with that background?

Comment: yes, it gives a perfect result with camscanner