# Opencv: ideas to get content inside user drawn circle on a white paper

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a white paper and a kid draws a circle on it. And there are some strokes inside the circle (randomly).

The white paper is pictured and may has many noises around the paper(background desk etc).

The problem is, how to extract all the content inside the kid drawn circle?

I think the process may involve:

1. Get ride of the backgournd noise, only see the white paper.
2. From the white paper find the circle using contour.
3. Get the content from the contour and save it to image.

How to complete the first step?

[image]

Comment: What about extract contours, order by area and pick the biggest?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8667818/5008845