# simple ANPR for Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I need some way to do ANPR(automatic number plate recognition) for one form of license plates on Windows Mobile, the plates are clear and numbers are big enough, anyone has a code to do that? I work on C# and its ok if the code is written on C++.

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to start writing your own code, before asking for assistance. Stackoverflow is not your personal Dev team :P

Comment: This kind of quesions are already discussed in SOF. Atleast visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981378/how-to-recognize-vehicle-license-number-plate-anpr-from-an-image. May be language used will be different. And there are plenty of papers on this out there on net. Google it.

Comment: Thank you Abid, the problem is Compact Frame is very limited and will take long time in programming, so I though maybe some one already did it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice license plate SDK also available for Windows CE/Mobile.

Please try http://www.dtksoft.com/dtkanpr.php

regards

Josef

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It's free and open source and very fast/accurate.  The code is written in C++ so it should be possible to run it on Windows Mobile as well.