# how to auto censor/blur numberplates with js?

Tags: javascript, blur, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Does anyone know a nice way to automatically blur /censor number plates /license plates from  jpegs preferably in javascript!? Or do all of you do this by hand? Couldn't figure one out yet...

Comment: not sure what to think about this question. Have you looked at other generic find and blur pattern libraries. to find a library that exclusivity does license plates seems a bit far fetched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981378/how-to-recognize-vehicle-license-number-plate-anpr-from-an-image?rq=1 although the linked answer does not directly address blurring.

Comment: @BobBrown yes you're right...

Comment: @bitoiu: i just thought this would be a common problem. which ones would you use (eg. how would you solve this problem?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is going to be reliably recognizing the area of the image that is the number plate.  Although there are image processing libraries for JavaScript, I'm not sure they're suitable to what you want to do.

Unless you have a zillion of these, blur them by hand; it'll be less work.

A place to start for further reading: http://www.licenseplaterecognition.com/

Comment: but anyway thanks for your quick answer and this link:)